# Partition SD Card?

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

I want to partition the SD card so that I can use Apps2SD application (on my Android phone, a Samsung GT-i5503). I just would like to know if I can partition my SD card using "Computer Management" in Windows? If not, how can I partition my SD card?

Comment: You can, if you use an SD card reader on your computer, or if you have a rooted ROM that has commands that allow you to partition a device.

Comment: @EboMike: I can't create a second partition in computer management. I need to create 2 partitions.