# Correctly partition microSDHC card

Tags: partitioning, formatting, android, sd-card, alignment

I temporarily used my microSDHC card for flashing a BeagleBone Black embedded device.  [This process involved overwriting the entire card with a binary image that contained two partitions](http://circuitco.com/support/index.php?title=Updating_The_Software).

Now I would like to use the card in my Android phone (Galaxy Note 2) again.  So it needs to be repartitioned with proper alignment and reformatted, preferably with ExFAT.

I tried using the SD Association [official SD Formatter tool, version 4.0](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) ([link to faster download](http://download.cnet.com/SD-Formatter/3000-2094_4-75883295.html)) since it allegedly ensures good performance.  Since performance depends on partition alignment, I thought it would recreate a single large partition covering the card, properly aligned.  It does not.  Instead it reformatted only 70MB capacity which was left by the BeagleBone Black imaging process.

What method or tool(s) can be used in Windows 8, 64-bit to optimize my card for use on a Android phone with ExFAT support, like my GN2?

---

Here is a closely related question -- [SD card shrinks in allowable size after copying disk image](https://superuser.com/questions/351554/sd-card-shrinks-in-allowable-size-after-copying-disk-image) -- but I am using Windows 8 and also concerned about proper alignment.  And that question was never satisfactorily resolved.

---

Note: "Use Linux" is not a valid answer to this question.  The short partition was created from inside Windows, using raw writes to the disk.  A valid partition table can be created in the same way.  Just because the Disk Management tool bundled with Windows can't do this doesn't mean that another OS is needed.

Comment: Just because someone didn't accept the answer(s) given doesn't mean it's not the same question.  That and the procedures between Windows 7 and 8 would be almost identical.  Did you attempt the suggestions in [grawity's answer](http://superuser.com/a/351975/23133)?

Comment: @techie007: Are you confused about the difference between Windows 8 and Linux?

Comment: Uhmm, no?  Are you allergic to temporarily booting from a Linux CD? :)  Aside from that one program you tried, what else have you attempted?  Have you tried using DiskPart in Windows to clear everything off?  anyhow, if you'd like newer/better/different answers to the existing question, perhaps consider [placing a bounty](http://superuser.com/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: @techie007: I feel that there is (1) demand for solution to this problem that doesn't involve changing BIOS settings or installing a hypervisor and (2) a need for the question to be written in such a way  that includes keywords such as *partition* and *alignment*.  I see the fact that I found the other question only after writing mine as proof that the other question's discoverability is poor.

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/304805/partition-sd-card) is also similar, but wholly lacking any information about alignment, filesystems, etc.